# Deleting rows in a dataframe that reference IDs that do not exist in another (R)?

Tags: r, dataframe, string-matching

I have more of a conceptual question. I am looking for a way of deleting the entire row out of a dataframe if it contains a reference to data that doesn't exist in a second dataframe. The code below will produce you a data set for this problem.

```
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8)
v2 <- 100
nodedf <- data.frame(v1, v2)
colnames(nodedf)  <- ("nid", "extra_variable") 

v3 <- c(1, 2)
v4 <- c(1, 5)
v5 <- c(2, 6)
v6 <- c(3, 7)
v7 <- c(4, 9)

elementdf <- data.frame(v3, v4, v5, v6, v7)
colnames(elementdf)  <- c("eid", "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4")
```

Basically, I want any row from `elementdf`deleted if it references a node ids (n1, n2, n3, n4) that does not exist in `nodedf`. I know it's probably a rather simple problem, but I am really not so great at this kind of stuff. Thanks.

EDIT: now I am looking to do the reverse, where I want to delete rows of nodedf that make reference to nodes that do not exist in elementdf.

At first I tried to just re-arrange the old code chunk like so:

```
orphannodesbye<- nodedf[apply(nodedf[,1], 1, function(x) all(x %in% elementdf[,2:5])),]
```

However, I get an error message:

```
Error in apply(nodedf[, 1], 1, function(x) all(x %in% elementdf[, 2:5])) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

I would like the output to be the whole df with both fields (or more, as my actual dataset has more) `nid` and `extra_variable`.

Comment: From your example, it doesn't seem like anything from `nodedf` should be deleted (since all nodes in `nodedf` appear in `elementdf`. Do you mean if, say, `v1` include `9`, that the row with the `9` should be deleted?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. I just changed a value in the data now to reflect that.

Comment: Check out my modified answer. The apply statement is really necessary since we're just doing some set matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a base R solution

```
elementdf[apply(elementdf[,-1], 1, function(x) all(x %in% nodedf$nid)),]
```

Explanation:

The `apply` works by "applying" a function (a custom one in this case) to each row (the variable `x` in the function) of the object `elementdf`. If we wanted to do this by columns we would change the `1` to a `2`.

The function we are using looks at each element in `x` (a row in `elementdf`) and tests if it is also in `nodedf`. The `%in%` is a special function which returns a vector of logicals, an element for each in `x`. The `all` function returns `TRUE` if all elements are `TRUE` (meaning all of them are in `nodedf`) and `FALSE` otherwise.

So in the end, the apply statement will return a vector of logicals, depending on whether each row has elements found in `nodedf`.

---

To get the values in each row that are not in `nodedf`, you could do

```
apply(elementdf[,-1], 1, function(x) x[!(x %in% nodedf$nid)])
```

which you'll notice is already pretty similar to the line of code above. Except in this case, the `apply` statement will return a list. From the example you gave, it will a list of length 2 where the first element is `numeric(0)` and the second element is a vector containing 7. If you have multiple offenders in one row, each will be shown.

---

To remove the rows in `nodedf` which do not have references in `elementdf`, you could do

```
nodedf[nodedf$nid %in% unique(unlist(elementdf[,-1])),]
```

The `unique(unlist(...))` part just grabs all the unique values in `elementdf[,-1]`, converting them to a numeric vector.

Comment: This is great, thank you. Could it be modified to return a result that shows which element ids were eliminated? If you could also break down how the code is deleting the row? I see it's apply acting on `elementdf` row-wise and character matching was used, but which part of the code is telling it to delete?

Comment: @hmnoidk When you say elementid, do you mean an index of the rows that will be removed or the value(s) that caused the row to be removed (in this case, the 7)?

Comment: The values (e.g. 7).

Comment: @hmnoidk The edit should answer your question. Let me know if there's anything unclear.

Comment: Thanks, mickey. One problem I realized is that if I run the code with nid 2 missing instead of 7, it deletes everything since there is nid = 2 in the first row, but since the next row is eid = 2, it also deletes this. Any way to isolate it to only the n1,n2, etc. values?

Comment: @hmnoidk Ah yes, I made the edit. The `[,-1]` removes the first column.

Comment: I used this same code block in reverse to remove nodes that were no longer referenced in the elementdf. e.g. `nodedf[apply(nodedf, 1, function(x) all(x %in% elementdf[,2:5])),]`. However, I've noticed that it stops working when `nodedf` has more than one field. I return the following error if I try to base it on `$nid`:

`Error in apply(sampledf[[1]], 1, function(x) all(x %in% sampleeiddf[,  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length` 

I'm not sure why it won't work.

Comment: If I'm understanding you, you want to remove the nodes in `nodedf` that are not found at all in `elementdf[,2:5]`? You might want to try something like `nodedf$nid[nodedf$nid %in% as.numeric(unlist(elementdf[,-1]))]`. Since `nodedf$nid` is a vector, `apply` will return that error. (Note that `dim(nodedf$nid)` is `NULL`.) If you wanted to use an apply on a vector, take a look at `?lapply` or `?tapply`.

Comment: Yes, except I would like the output to include the additional fields too, however only value-matching based on nid. I would ultimately like it as a dataframe, yes. I've tried mucking around with lapply but end up with similar errors.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding. Perhaps you could edit the question (or ask a new one) so you can show exactly the kind of output you're looking for. I've got a vague idea of what you're asking, but it would be helpful if you would describe it in more detail outside of a comment.

Comment: I edited my original post so that may clear things up.